# Windows - route traffic via 2 different network interfaces

Tags: windows, routing, ip-routing

I have Windows XP systems with two GPRS modems hooked in. There are two copies of my program running, each one connecting to same server in 3rd party network via TCP socket(s).

My goal is to "bind" traffic from each copy to specified modem (i.e. simulate two different GPRS-connected users from server point of view)

Thanks

Update: I can tweak the code, but of course, external solution is preferred

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Outgoing IP traffic can be routed through different gateways based on the destination network (or address), but if all your connections are going to the same server, you can only follow a single IP route to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this relatively easily by creating two virtual machines, and configure each VM to use a different network interface card in the host XP machine.

Comment: He doesn't have two network interface cards, he has two dial-up connections.

Comment: You can assign different hardware to different guests via PCI pass-through, etc.  My experience is with KVM hosts, but I imagine there's a more desktoppy equivalent in VirtualBox or VMWare.  IF not, XP guests on KVM hosts work fine.

Answer (score 1):

What about http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/, forcebindip which binds applications to a specific interface, not sure about the ability of instancing the same application, but you can try this out.